# How can I convert Jquery code to pure javascript code

Tags: javascript, jquery, post, pagination

guys. I'm creating a pagination with PHP and Javascript (load more button). However, the paging system is the only system on the site that is using Jquery. It is loading an entire library, affecting the load time of the website (SEO).

**The code in jquery:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.load-more').click(function(){
        var row = Number($('#row').val());
        var allcount = Number($('#all').val());
        var rowperpage = 6;
        row = row + rowperpage;

        if(row <= allcount){
            $("#row").val(row);

            $.ajax({
                url: 'getData.php',
                type: 'post',
                data: {row:row},
                beforeSend:function(){
                    $(".load-more").text("Carregando...");
                },
                success: function(response){
                    setTimeout(function() {
                        $(".post:last").after(response).show().fadeIn("slow");
                        var rowno = row + rowperpage;
                        if(rowno > allcount){
                            $(".load-more").prop('disabled', true);
                            $('.load-more').css("background","grey");
                        }else{
                            $(".load-more").text("Carregar Mais");
                        }
                    }, 2000);

                }
            });
        } }); });
```

I tried to recreate the code, but it is not working. According to the Chrome error identifier, there are no problems with the code. Does anyone have any idea what is it?

**The code in Javascript (show the content, but not in the same way with jquery)**

```
function myFunction(){
    var row = document.getElementById('row').value;
    var allcount = document.getElementById('all').value;
    var rowperpage = 6;
    rowSoma = row + rowperpage;

    if(rowSoma <= allcount){

        row = document.getElementById('row').value;

        var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
        request.open('POST', 'getData.php', true);
        request.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8');
        request.onreadystatechange = function() {

            if (request.readyState == 4 && request.status == 200) {
                var data = request.response;
                console.log(data);
                document.getElementById("myElement").innerHTML = data;

            var rowno = row + rowperpage;
            if(rowno > allcount){
                document.getElementById("load-more").disabled = true;
            } else { }
            }
            };
          request.onerror = function() {
            // There was a connection error of some sort
          };
        request.send(rowSoma);
    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: *but not in the same way* so, whats the difference? oh, right, no fade and no delay - use CSS for fade, use settimeout for delay (that part is just like the jquery code)

Comment: pure javascript code is not sending rowSoma to the form and I don't know if                                        document.getElementById("myElement").innerHTML = data;
have the same function as $(".post:last").after(response).show().fadeIn("slow");

Comment: actually it is ... but jquery is sending a parameter called row, with the value of row ... your XHR request is just sending a number

Comment: I ajusted the php form to receive rowSoma

Comment: you mean just a number, no paramater name - show the PHP code, because this code IS sending data in the post

Comment: `request.send({row:rowSoma});`

Comment: you could easily debug this one by opening the Network tab in console, try out the jQuery code and than try the JS one and inspect the difference in data you're sending.. `data: {row:row},` != `request.send(rowSoma);`